# Handling multiple queueEvent / Runnable button presses on Android?

Tags: java, android, events, button, runnable

When using Java / Android how should I be dealing with multiple fast button presses when using something like queueEvent(new Runnable() {blah blah blah}? When I click the button fast the second event is firing before the first event has completed and messing it up. How do I isolate them and deal with them one at a time? At the moment I have in UI thread...

```
public void passOnButtonPress(final int buttonId) {
    queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mRenderer.handleInteraction(buttonId);
        }});
}
```

...and in worker thread...

```
public void handleInteraction(final int buttonId){
    int command =  BlockZOpenGl20.getCommand();
    switch(buttonId)
    { 
    case R.id.rotateYminus: rotateYMinus
```

I'm using runnable as I'm creating a 3D game and using OpenGL ES 2 so extending...

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

and implementing a renderer...

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer

I've read that these should be on their own thread but this is where the game logic is so button presses on UI thread get chucked across...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Added code to question Darish...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem with a work around. I had an onDrawFrame routine that had numerous states controlled by amount of time elapsed...

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    if(frame == Blockz.ANIMATION_FRAME_RATE){
        if(animationState == AnimationState.MOVE)
        {
            do something...
            once game logic complete
            animationState == AnimationState.NEUTRAL
```

I put a guard around the routine that controls user input so it would only run another command once game logic was in understood state.

```
public void handleInteraction(final int keyCode){
    if(animationState == AnimationState.NEUTRAL) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Second event arriving after the first one can not be the fault of the glSurfaceview. If you look at the documentation you'll see that "queueEvent" adds the event in a synchronized block to an arraylist, where the event is later retrieved from.

This code also works. Notice that every time the touch position is updated, a new event is added to the queue and the events never swap.

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                ...
                // Calculate normalized value and everything
                ...

                glSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mainRenderer.handleOnTouch(action, normalizedX, normalizedY);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Also, I recommend you to separate the renderer from the glSurfaceView for clarity.

TLDR:

Your issue is caused by this line:

```
int command =  BlockZOpenGl20.getCommand();
```

Where you probably reverse the order.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer andras.  I don't think I explain this problem very clearly. I'd press a "move" button and game would start to react. If I pressed the "move" button again too quickly a new move event would start before the previous one finished so game logic would fail. For instance counter would jump through a wall. I've solved it with a work around.

Answer (score 0):

> Handling multiple queueEvent / Runnable button presses on Android?

You don't need to use new Runnable(), just receive the button calls in the UI thread and it will not get messed up.